# Strange Build Errors in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have this method declaration in an interface:

```
#import "LotPolygon.h"

...

@interface LotLattice : NSObject {

... //member variables

}

- (LotPolygon *) lotPolygonContainingCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord;

...

@end
```

The compiler gives this error for the method declaration:

> Expected ')' before LotPolygon.

If I comment it out, the code builds with the warning you'd expect (Lotlattice may not respond...) and functions and that method works just as it's supposed to. But that warning really bothers me because it makes it less likely that I'll see other warnings that I need to see. I'd really like it to compile with the proper declaration, and I just can't see anything wrong with that line.

I've even tried moving that line around in the file to see if it was really a line right before it that was pissing off Xcode, but no--It really doesn't like that line. Any ideas?

Comment: have you any #define used anywhere anywhere? And if so, ensure you don't have a ; at the end of any ones where there shouldn't be. Only reason I mention it is its a simple typo that causes that error for me sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that the compiler doesn't know about the `LotPolygon` class.  Either include the header file that defines that class, or add a *forward declaration*:

```
// This says that LotPolygon is the name of a class, but it doesn't define
// anything else about it
@class LotPolygon;

- (LotPolygon *) lotPolygonContainingCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord;
```

Comment: Yeah, I was able to fix it using different combinations of @class in the .h files along with full #import statements in the .m files. I still don't really understand why this is necessary--as you can see from my excerpt, the #import for LotPolygon.h is in there... Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

XCode usually print that error when it couldn't find LotPolygon declaration. Make sure it can find the @interface and the @implementation of that object